# Finding the correct CSS Selector to put in a Trigger

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am trying to add the correct CSS selector for Click Element in (Google Tag Manager)

This is for the following action:

https://aurumiceland.com/pages/join-our-insider-list-newsletter

Click on the button Subscribe.

I tried adding the class from the Thank you Message but it either doesnt trigger at all or it triggers when just opening the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will propose this CSS selector

```
div[class*='klaviyo-form'] form button
```

But just wonder did you already try some CSS selector first?

---

Not sure why it won't work in your end.

I test it with my GTM container and looks like it's working

Here is the trigger setting

[image]

Comment: I tried every one I can think of. 

I check the ChromeDev Tools and use every div class I can find with a . in front. Doesn't seem to work.

I tried your CSS Selectors but it doesnt seem to work either.

I am using 

Element Visbility and tried both CSS Selector or ID

Comment: I add up the trigger and setting and the preview looks working on my end. Not sure I miss anything